# Why capabilities() are not the same between R from the console and RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, cairo

I am trying to understand why `capabilities()` are not the same between R running in the console and RStudio despite that both use the same R binaries.

In the console:

[image]

In RStudio:

[image]

I only have 1 R installation:

```
> Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because dynamic libraries may need to be changed by RStudio for its display purposes?  On Linux it is well known that via [the `LD_PRELOAD` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) you can get yourself different libraries (for, say, debug versions). Maybe `Cairo` gets in the way?  (And there are add-on packages for Cairo-based graphics too, and now the [ragg](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=ragg) package and ....)  It could also be on purpose.

In my case (on Linux using the CRAN-mirrored Ubuntu binary by Michael based on my Debian package of R), all `capabilities()` appear to be the same and `TRUE` (with the exception of `aqua`, but RStudio Server for example has `X11` as `FALSE` where as RStudio (desktop) still has it.  All seems to make sense to me :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there an easy way to fix that?

Comment: Wouldn't that involve _changing RStudio_ which, as an open source program, is possible but likely 'lots of work'.  You haven't really motivated what _really_ drives you. Do you need a cairo-capable device? There have long been add-on packages for that.